# Can I use Facebook's fb:friend-selector in an iframe?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to use Facebook's `fb:friend-selector` FBML tag, but my application is running in an iframe. Is it possible to use this tag in an iframe? If so does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is definitely possible, but you have to use [Facebook Connect](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) and [XFBML](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/XFBML).  Specifically, you want to use the [fb:serverfbml](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/) tag to get fb:friend-selector working.  I have an iframe app whereby I use all of this and the fb:friend-selector in the standard "invite friends to your app" context, and it works great.

Here is the body of my template file, which gets output inside the body of my iframe:

```html
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 650px;"> 
<script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml> 
        <fb:request-form
            action="http://example.com/invite/sent"
            method="POST"
            invite="true"
            type="My App"
            content="Try out my app!
                <fb:req-choice url='http://your-facebook-canvas-url'
                label='<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Accept button text",ENT_QUOTES); ?>'
                /> 
            " > 
            <fb:multi-friend-selector
                showborder="false"
                actiontext="Invite your friends to try My App."
                exclude_ids="<?php echo $excludeIds; ?>"
                rows="3"
            /> 
        </fb:request-form> 
    </fb:fbml>
</script> 
</fb:serverfbml>
```

In the footer of the page, I have the standard Facebook Connect code, which will load and render the fb:serverfbml contents:

```html
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(
        ["CanvasUtil"],
        function(){
             FB.XdComm.Server.init('/xd_receiver.html');
             FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
        }
    );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ FB.Facebook.init("Your Facebook API Key", "/xd_receiver.html"); });   
</script>
```

That should be all you need (fill in your own options where applicable, of course).  You'll have to set up Facebook Connect to work with a cross-domain receiver file.  I suggest following the [rendering XFBML steps](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/XFBML#Rendering_XFBML).

Comment: You say you have to used Facebook Connect. From the documentation there appears to be two links to FeatureLoader.js one with Connect and one without Connect in the url. I am not sure what to make of this and very confused.

Comment: While the answer suggested by Zombat works, you should use the new [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) instead of the older JS SDK his code sample uses. The XFBML will remain the same, but the JS code will look different. Here's a live example: http://apps.facebook.com/fbrelll/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector.

Comment: @daaku - yes, this question was asked/answered more than a year ago, so it is out of date now.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that, I think I noticed May, but not the 09 part when I saw the date. The new SDK didn't even exist then :)

Comment: Thank you sooo so much for this answer.  Works perfectly (when changed to the new API)

Comment: How do you grab the selected UID's from this ?

Answer (score 8):

The question in this thread is still relevant but the answer is out of date.  You should use the new javascript SDK.  This should replace the second code snippet posted by zombat

```html
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   FB.init({appId: 'your app id',
       status: true,
       cookie: true,
       xfbml: true});
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
     if (response.session) {
       // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
     } else {
       // The user has logged out
     }
   });
</script>
```

more info here: http://www.clickonchris.com/2010/11/facebook-javascript-sdks/

Answer (score 3):

Since that are a lot of questions about the friend-selector within an iframe.

Guys the correct sintax now is `<fb:serverfbml width="650px">`

Answer (score 0):

one MAJOR and IMPORTANT point that gets missed is that many of you (including me) stick in scripts just about anywhere... but the "FB" load.js file needs to be loaded *IMMEDIATELY* after the body tag.

at least this is what I found to make everything work and humm accordingly. I found it on a post on some other site (wasn't sure if I should post it here or not...) but it came after spending countless hours, doing the above aforementioned - as well as following every other 1,2, 3 step punch into getting the iframe to size properly...

and now i've gotten it to work :)