# FB Developer: Capture POST variables after multi-friend-selector

Tags: .net, javascript, facebook

Using this:
[Can I use Facebook's fb:friend-selector in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820421/can-i-use-facebooks-fbfriend-selector-in-an-iframe)
I created a multi-friend selector in my IFRAME FB application.

I want to know if the user selected any users for invite so I can reward him with extra points. In the developer WIKI I saw that [ids] is transferred to requested page via POST. But how I can capture the values if I'm using JS/.NET? (Preferably through .NET so I can easily save values in the DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel like an idiot...

Had to do:

```
Request.Form["ids[]"]
```

in order to get the values...