# Facebook iframe canvas friend selector

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml, friend, facebook-iframe

I am in the process of converting my FBML application to iframe as per Facebook's new requirements:

> **No new FBML applications** We will stop allowing new FBML applications, but will continue to support existing FBML tabs and applications. Instead, we recommend using IFrames.
>   --Facebook Roadmap http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Now my application allows you to post your creation to another users wall (or a fan/group page). My old application used the FBML [fb:friend-selector](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/friend-selector/) to allow the user to pick a friend, and it would grab the id of them, and post on their wall using FBJS [Facebook.streamPublish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/streamPublish).

My question is, how do i go about doing the same thing in an iFrame? As far as i am aware, the only option i have is:

- Use FBML in the iframe and have the js SDK turn it into an ugly, hard to access iframe (which also defies the point of sticking it all in a iframe in the 1st place, as it is going to be removed at somepoint?)
- Create my own friend selector using graph api or something. Have yet to see a working example of that in action, makes me wonder if it is possible.

Are there any other options out there, or does anyone have a working custom friend selector in an iFrame?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [XFBML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) in the iFrame (the same way you would handle this on an off-canvas FB Connect application).  Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820421/can-i-use-facebooks-fbfriend-selector-in-an-iframe) with more details.

Comment: But with FBML heading for the trash, is this really the best method of approach? and beside which the <fb:serverfbml> tag, is basically just creating an iframe in your iframe, isn't it then hard to obtain the id of the selected user?

Comment: FBML isn't heading for the trash.  FBML Canvas Applications are. They intend to continue to support iFrames applications.

Comment: The policy change you're concerned about only applies to the right-hand radio button in the app settings: http://drktd.com/43mx

Comment: Thank you for your input, i will try pull it together using the XFBML method